# WiFi adapter sees networks but can't connect to one

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux

I am using Kali Linux (6.0.0-kali6-amd64) VM VirtualBox; distribution version is 2022.4.

My problem is that my **VM sees my wireless WiFi adapter as well as WiFi networks** but it **cannot connect to my home WiFi**; it just loads on top and then nothing happens. I've also verified the WiFi password.

Here is my VM settings:
[image: VMsettings]

`iwconfig` outputs this:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`ifconfig` output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::1ebf:ceff:fef9:3eec  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1c:bf:ce:f9:3e:ec  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 247  bytes 49045 (47.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 34  bytes 2536 (2.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 34  bytes 2536 (2.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 1c:bf:ce:f9:3e:ec  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`airmon-ng` output:

```
PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

phy2    wlan0           rtl8xxxu        Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192EU 802.11b/g/n WLAN Adapter
```

and a snippet of `dmesg`:

```
[   51.667045] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=818b, bcdDevice= 2.00
[   51.667060] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   51.667064] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11n NIC
[   51.667068] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[   51.667071] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 1CBFCEF93EEC
[   52.324916] usb 1-2: Vendor: Realtek
[   52.324927] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11n NIC
[   52.324928] usb 1-2: Serial not available.
[   52.324930] usb 1-2: rtl8192eu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[   52.324933] usb 1-2: 00: 29 81 00 7c 01 40 03 00
[   52.324935] usb 1-2: 08: 40 74 04 50 14 00 00 00
[   52.324937] usb 1-2: 10: 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29
[   52.324939] usb 1-2: 18: 29 2a 2a 01 ef ef ff ff
[   52.324940] usb 1-2: 20: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324941] usb 1-2: 28: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324943] usb 1-2: 30: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324944] usb 1-2: 38: ff ff 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e
[   52.324946] usb 1-2: 40: 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 02 ef ef
[   52.324947] usb 1-2: 48: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324948] usb 1-2: 50: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324950] usb 1-2: 58: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324951] usb 1-2: 60: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324952] usb 1-2: 68: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324954] usb 1-2: 70: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324955] usb 1-2: 78: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324956] usb 1-2: 80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324958] usb 1-2: 88: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324959] usb 1-2: 90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324960] usb 1-2: 98: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324962] usb 1-2: a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324963] usb 1-2: a8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324964] usb 1-2: b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324966] usb 1-2: b8: 20 20 1a 00 00 00 ff ff
[   52.324967] usb 1-2: c0: ff 01 00 10 00 00 00 ff
[   52.324968] usb 1-2: c8: 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324970] usb 1-2: d0: da 0b 8b 81 e6 47 02 1c
[   52.324971] usb 1-2: d8: bf ce f9 3e ec 09 03 52
[   52.324972] usb 1-2: e0: 65 61 6c 74 65 6b 0d 03
[   52.324974] usb 1-2: e8: 38 30 32 2e 31 31 6e 20
[   52.324975] usb 1-2: f0: 4e 49 43 00 ff ff ff ff
[   52.324977] usb 1-2: f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324978] usb 1-2: 100: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324979] usb 1-2: 108: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324981] usb 1-2: 110: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0d
[   52.324982] usb 1-2: 118: 03 00 05 00 30 00 00 00
[   52.324983] usb 1-2: 120: 00 93 ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324985] usb 1-2: 128: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324986] usb 1-2: 130: f6 a8 98 2d 03 92 98 00
[   52.324987] usb 1-2: 138: fc 8c 00 11 9b 44 02 0a
[   52.324989] usb 1-2: 140: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324990] usb 1-2: 148: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324991] usb 1-2: 150: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324993] usb 1-2: 158: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324994] usb 1-2: 160: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324995] usb 1-2: 168: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324997] usb 1-2: 170: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324998] usb 1-2: 178: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.324999] usb 1-2: 180: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325001] usb 1-2: 188: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325002] usb 1-2: 190: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325003] usb 1-2: 198: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325005] usb 1-2: 1a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325006] usb 1-2: 1a8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325007] usb 1-2: 1b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325009] usb 1-2: 1b8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325010] usb 1-2: 1c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325011] usb 1-2: 1c8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325013] usb 1-2: 1d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325014] usb 1-2: 1d8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325015] usb 1-2: 1e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325017] usb 1-2: 1e8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325018] usb 1-2: 1f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325019] usb 1-2: 1f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   52.325021] usb 1-2: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[   52.325025] usb 1-2: RTL8192EU MAC: 1c:bf:ce:f9:3e:ec
[   52.325028] usb 1-2: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[   52.325127] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[   52.325141] usb 1-2: Firmware revision 35.7 (signature 0x92e1)
[   56.675259] wlan0: authenticate with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55
[   56.712622] wlan0: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[   56.770859] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 1/3)
[   56.972198] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 2/3)
[   57.176291] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 3/3)
[   57.380097] wlan0: authentication with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 timed out
[   59.512267] wlan0: authenticate with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55
[   59.526914] wlan0: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[   59.610109] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 1/3)
[   59.839931] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 2/3)
[   60.042912] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 3/3)
[   60.246646] wlan0: authentication with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 timed out
[   62.823465] wlan0: authenticate with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55
[   62.837495] wlan0: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[   62.920954] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 1/3)
[   63.127163] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 2/3)
[   63.341663] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 3/3)
[   63.545829] wlan0: authentication with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 timed out
[   66.701140] wlan0: authenticate with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55
[   66.723709] wlan0: bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT
[   66.791810] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 1/3)
[   66.990248] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 2/3)
[   67.195451] wlan0: send auth to 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 (try 3/3)
[   67.404085] wlan0: authentication with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55 timed out
[   77.430039] wlan0: authenticate with 4b:22:77:3e:ab:55
```

and also `iwlist wlan0 scan` works fine too.

Comment: You're not telling us what you are using to connect, but are you running `wpa_supplicant`?

Comment: @Bib yes, it is shown in `airmon-ng check` command